# How to get which word is selected in span

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following scenario:
contents are displayed in div.
Users can select words from that content.
I am fetching selection of the user using `window.getselection().tostring()` method.

Now I want the location of the selected contents inside `span`/`div`.

For eg. Parent `div` has contents like this:

```
<span>abc xyz abc</span>
<div>abc xyz abc</div>
<span>abc xyz abc</span>
```

So if I select 1st abc from 1st span or I select 2nd abc in 1st span or I select abc abc from 1st span and second div then what will be the best way to highlight the selected part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How below solution can be useful

```js
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.setAttribute("style", "background-color: pink;");
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

Comment: Will this work with contents in 2 separate span/div?

Answer (score 0):

it works for me very well :

```
    import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const App = () => {

const spanInput=useRef();

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(spanInput.current.innerHTML)
    },[spanInput])


    return (
        <div>


       <span ref={spanInput}>test text</span>

        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: This won't work as I can't add reference to every child of div and because they are coming from api call. And also div is in iframe

Comment: Also I think this just logs the html of the reference. I want to highlight selected contents